# Emergent supersymmetry in tricritical Ising model

Tags: quantum-field-theory, condensed-matter, renormalization, supersymmetry, ising-model

In [TASI Lectures on Emergence of Supersymmetry, Gauge Theory and String in Condensed Matter Systems](https://arxiv.org/abs/1009.5127)  there is a statement that 2d supersymmetry can can emerge from the dilute Ising model:

$$
\beta H = -J \sum_{<i,j>} \sigma_i \sigma_j - \mu \sum_i \sigma_i^2
$$
where $\sigma = ±1$ represents a site with spin up or down, and $\sigma = 0$ represents a vacant site.

> The **tricritical point** is
> described by the $\phi^6$-theory:
>
> $$
> S = \int d^2x\, [(\partial_\mu \phi)^2 + \lambda_6 \phi^6]
> $$
> where $\phi ∼ \langle\sigma\rangle $ describes the magnetic order parameter.

> Although there is no fermion in
> this action, one can construct a **fermion field $\psi$ from a string of spins** through the Jordan-Wigner transformation. At the tricritical point, the scaling dimensions of $\phi^2$
> and $\psi$ differ exactly by 1/2.

> This is not an accident and these two fields form a multiplet under an
> **emergent supersymmetry**. More generally, the operators which are even (odd) under the $Z_2$ spin symmetry form the Neveu-Schwarz (Ramond) algebra. The dilute Ising model provides deformations of the underlying superconformal theory within $(−1)^F = 1$ sector, where $F$ is
> the fermion number.

I don't understand two statements:

**1) Why $\phi^6$ theory? How to understand this? Why not $\phi^4$? or $\phi^8$? or $\phi^4+\phi^6$?**

**2) One can construct fermions from strings of spins even in ordinary Ising model. Why does SUSY emerge in the dilute Ising model model but not in the Ising model?**

May be another formulation of my question is: **How to identify dilute Ising model with $c=7/10$ minimal model?**

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the first question. The statement is just that tuning this lattice model to its (tricritical) fixed point, the CFT is the minimal model with $c=7/10$. In this minimal model the Virasoro algebra is enhanced to super-Virasoro (see the discussion in Di Francesco). Other potentials for $\phi$ would be different continuum descriptions.

Comment: @4xion, first question is how relate lattice model to field theory? Second question is how to understand emergemce of SUSY on field level?

Comment: Have you read the discussion of the minimal models (and the superconformal models) in the Di Francesco CFT book (sec 7.4)? It addressed most of these questions I think

Comment: @4xion, as I understand, they consider such question in algebraic level. I am intrested in field theory description.

Comment: The continuum description of the lattice model is often called the Landau-Ginzburg theory, which is more general, but for the minimal models just amounts to different $\phi$ potentials. Look in 7.4.7 of Di Francesco or search around for LG theory

Comment: @4xion for me, must nontrivial step is obtain fermionic d.o.f. and susy in cintinum limit directly from lattice

Comment: Like you said the Ising model has fermions too, but it's just a different theory (with a different algebra and different symmetry). Once you believe that the critical theory is the $c=7/10$ minimal model, SUSY is just  a property of that theory, not sure if I know of a more physical explanation

Comment: Perhaps this is another point of confusion, in the continuum description of this lattice model, there are e.g. $\phi^2$ and $\phi^4$ terms in the Lagrangian, but the tricritical point is the point where we tune these operators to zero, leaving the Lagrangian you wrote above

Comment: @4xion, thank you, it is really helpful. But anyway I must obtain equal number of bosonic and fermionic d.o.f. in continum limit. May be another formulation of my question is: **how to identify dilute Ising model with $c=7/10$ minimal model?**

Answer (score 4):

The best reference I know of for recognizing the `dilute Ising model', or the Blume-Capel model as it is referred to, is Chapter 14.3 in [Mussardo's Statistical Field Theory Text book](https://oxford.universitypressscholarship.com/view/10.1093/oso/9780198788102.001.0001/oso-9780198788102). The basic steps are

1. A Hubbard Stratonovich transformation of the Ising model gives a $\phi^4$ Landau-Ginsberg model. When you include vacancies, you need to go to $\phi^6$. This is remarkable in that the LG theory is exact in some sense, rather than phenomenological.
2. Construct the Kac table of the $\mathcal{M}_4$ minimal model with central charge $c = \frac{7}{10}$.  You can identify both the even and odd sectors now with your knowledge of the $\phi^6$ LG model with both a spin and a duality $\mathbb{Z}_2$ symmetry. (See chapter 11.6 in the Reference).
3. As a check, using the  conformal weights of the primary fields you construct with $\mathcal{M}_4$ you can match the correlation scalings with the critical exponents for the tricritical Ising model universality class.